# Get all the values from JSON based on keyname

Tags: c#, json, .net

I got JSON from some process as following:

```
{
"Nodename": "Host1",
"OperatingSystem": "OS",
"Release": "3.6.2.1",
"Stats": [{
        "Timestamp": "11/18/2021 18:31:58",
        "Processes": [{
                "Timestamp": "11/18/2021 18:31:58",
                "Processname": "process1",
                "CpuPercent": 0,
                "MemoryPercent": 0.16,
            }, {
                "Timestamp": "11/18/2021 18:31:58",
                "Processname": "process2",
                "CpuPercent": 0,
                "MemoryPercent": 0.46,
            }, {
                "Timestamp": "11/18/2021 18:31:58",
                "Processname": "process3",
                "CpuPercent": 0,
                "MemoryPercent": 0.69,
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "Timestamp": "11/18/2021 18:32:08",
        "Processes": [{
                "Timestamp": "11/18/2021 18:32:08",
                "Processname": "process1",
                "CpuPercent": 0,
                "MemoryPercent": 0.16,
            }, {
                "Timestamp": "11/18/2021 18:32:09",
                "Processname": "process2",
                "CpuPercent": 0,
                "MemoryPercent": 0.46,
            }, {
                "Timestamp": "11/18/2021 18:32:09",
                "Processname": "process3",
                "CpuPercent": 0,
                "MemoryPercent": 0.69,
            }
        ]
    }, {...}
]}
```

I need to sum all the values based on process as key in another JSON like

```
{
    "process1": {
        "AverageCpu": xxx,
        "AverageMemory": yyy,
    },
    "process2": {
        "AverageCpu": xxx,
        "AverageMemory": yyy,
    },
    "process3": {
        "AverageCpu": xxx,
        "AverageMemory": yyy,
    }
}
```

I am trying with normal foreach with "groupby" but not able to get actual result.
I do not want to iterate many times as this source JSON can be huge.

Thanks

Comment: change json value to an object, and then use that object to create another object, which is what you need, then change again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools such as [Json2Csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) to generate the classes based on JSON.

```cs
public class Process
{
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    public string Processname { get; set; }

    public int CpuPercent { get; set; }

    public double MemoryPercent { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    public List<Process> Processes { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string Nodename { get; set; }

    public string OperatingSystem { get; set; }

    public string Release { get; set; }

    public List<Stat> Stats { get; set; }
}

public class GroupedProcessStat
{
    public double AverageCpu {get;set;}
    public double AverageMemory {get;set;}
}
```

1. Deserialize JSON to `Root` class via `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`.
2. Retrieve `processes` via `.SelectMany()` from `System.Linq`.
3. `.GroupBy()` `processName` and convert it to dictionary via `.ToDictionary()`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

```cs
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
var processes = root.Stats
    .SelectMany(x => x.Processes)
    .ToList();
        
var groupedProcessDict = processes.GroupBy(x => x.Processname)
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.Key,
        x => new GroupedProcessStat
            {
                AverageCpu = x.Average(y => y.CpuPercent),
                AverageMemory = x.Average(y => y.MemoryPercent)
            });
        
var groupedProcessJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupedProcessDict);
Console.WriteLine(groupedProcessJson);
```

> Output

```json
{"process1":{"AverageCpu":0.0,"AverageMemory":0.16},"process2":{"AverageCpu":0.0,"AverageMemory":0.46},"process3":{"AverageCpu":0.0,"AverageMemory":0.69}}
```

[Sample Program on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LgVWWu)